# Show custom contact facets in Sitecore experience profile

Tags: experience-profile, xconnect, contact-facets

I'm building a custom xConnect client api which is supposed to send data to xConnect. Now I've created a custom facet as an extension to the contact model.

The facet is successfully created and set for the contact. I'm trying to show the facet's properties in the Sitecore experience profile, and I was wondering if this is possible?

I'm using Sitecore 9 by the way.

Comment: I haven't tried but i asume it would work the same as it would in Sitecore 8.2, this post explains how to do it: http://reyrahadian.com/2016/08/27/sitecore-8-extending-experience-profile-part-2-displaying-contact-facet-simple-properties/ The only part where it should differ would be the part where you actualy get the Facet data to display

Comment: I'm looking for a way to show the properties without having to modify the sitecore application, so that I don't have to create a new tab for each facet.

Answer (score 1):

I am going with the assumption that you are wanting to add the facet data to the Experience Profile View and not the grid. Having done it with Speak and never wanting to do it that way again. The Express Tab project makes it a million times easier to get the data in there. Love it.

https://github.com/JeffDarchuk/EPExpressTab

The resources are available on nuget. https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPExpressTab/

[image]

Comment: Would I have to instantiate an xConnect client in Sitecore as well to populate the tab with the contact's facet data, or is there some simple way to achieve this in Sitecore? Because if I would have to instantiate the client manually, I'd have two clients that communicate with xConnect, which is what I'm trying to avoid. I'm hoping Sitecore 9 has created some new functionality to extract data from xConnect within Sitecore.

Comment: Samir, nope. Sitecore itself uses xConnect as a client, so it needs to use the xConnecr client as well.  The infrastructure of xConnect should be sufficient to support that.